# Yup /w Formik File Upload Validation

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

I'm using Yup with Formik and i run into problem, where I need to validate my file-upload. Validation works, but I'm facing problem, because I can't submit form without file. I need to make it notRequired and because initialValue is undefined it test that undefined value.

My code:

```
    attachment: Yup.mixed()
        .nullable()
        .notRequired()
        .test("FILE_SIZE", "Uploaded file is too big.", value => value && value.size <= FILE_SIZE)
        .test("FILE_FORMAT", "Uploaded file has unsupported format.", value => value && SUPPORTED_FORMATS.includes(value.type))
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem here is that the two `.test` are making it not valid.

`value => value && value.size <= FILE_SIZE` and `value => value && SUPPORTED_FORMATS.includes(value.type)` will fail every time `value` is `undefined` or `null`, but it shouldn't fail by what you are saying.

So you need to do some checking. If the `value` is `null` or `undefined`, it's valid, but if it isn't, do other checkings.

So what you need is

```
attachment: Yup.mixed()
    .nullable()
    .notRequired()
    .test("FILE_SIZE", "Uploaded file is too big.", 
        value => !value || (value && value.size <= FILE_SIZE))
    .test("FILE_FORMAT", "Uploaded file has unsupported format.", 
        value => !value || (value && SUPPORTED_FORMATS.includes(value.type)))
```

Comment: How to validate number of uploaded files? for example, less than 3 files, it will display invalid feedback.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'useRef' to access file size.

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react'
import { Field, ErrorMessage, useFormik, Formik, Form } from 'formik'

    const filesharhe_ref = useRef()
        const validationSchema = Yup.object({
                myfile: Yup.mixed().test('FILE_SIZE', "Uploaded file is too big."
                ,(value) => {
                   return(
                    value && filesharhe_ref.current ?
                        (filesharhe_ref.current.files[0].size<=FILE_SIZE? true: false)
                         : true)
                }),
            })
    
    <!-- Component-->

    <Field innerRef={filesharhe_ref} type="file" name="myfile" />
    <ErrorMessage name='myfile'  />
```

don't forget to define FILE_SIZE.

Also you can check file format:

```
Yup.mixed().test('FILE_SIZE', "Uploaded file is too big."
                ,(value) => {
                   return(
                    value && filesharhe_ref.current ?
                        (filesharhe_ref.current.files[0].size<=FILE_SIZE? true: false)
                         : true)
                }).test(
                'FILE_Type', "Not valid!"
                , (value) => {
                    console.log(filesharhe_ref.current.files[0])
                    return (
                        value && filesharhe_ref.current ?
                            (SUPPORTED_FORMATS.includes(filesharhe_ref.current.files[0].type) ? true : false)
                            : true)
                }
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
attachedFile: Yup.mixed().test(
    "fileType",
    "Unsupported File Format",
    (value) => {
      if (value) {
        return (
          value.type === "image/jpeg" ||
          value.type === "image/jpg" ||
          value.type === "image/png" ||
          value.type === "application/pdf"
        );
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }
  ),
```